# Using JavaScript code for navigating (InnerHTML)

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm using this code below for the navigation system on my site, the purpose is to open an HTML page within a div .. (InnerHTML), but, when I'm clicking one of my menu links I'm getting the JavaScript notification "Problem: " (see "else" in the JavaScript code block). This code is fixed (good) for SEO aspect.

Can someone please tell me what the problem with it is? I'm trying to preserve the code as it is as much as possible.

Thank you in advance for your help!

JavaScript code:

```
function processAjax(url) 
{ 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Non-IE browsers 
        req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        req.onreadystatechange = targetDiv; 
        try { 
            req.open("GET", url, true); 
        }
        catch (e) { 
             alert(e); 
        } 
        req.send(null); 
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 
          req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
             if (req) { 
               req.onreadystatechange = targetDiv; 
               req.open("GET", url, true); 
               req.send(); 

    } 
} 
return false; 
} 

function targetDiv() { 
    if (req.readyState == 4) { // Complete 
          if (req.status == 200) { // OK response 
              document.getElementById("containerDiv").innerHTML = req.responseText; 
          } else { 
            alert("Problem: " + req.statusText); 
          } 
    } 
}
```

In HTML body:

```
<a onclick="return processAjax(this.href)"  href="example.html">CLICK ME</a>
<div id="containerDiv"></div>
```

Comment: `this code is fixed (good) for SEO aspect` That is not true at all.  Your code has nothing to do with SEO, except that it preserves `href`s.

Comment: If you're getting the "Problem" alert, your AJAX request is hitting an HTTP error of some sort.  It might be a permissions problem, or you might have the wrong path/url.

Answer (score 0):

The server returned a non-200 response. If you're using a debugger like Firebug, Chrome Developer, or IE Developer, check the Network tab to see exactly where your XHR went, and what the response was.

Comment: SLaks i didn't explained myself good, i ment than this way i can generate a google sitemap xml file so the links i have will be shown